# Why doesn't Visual Studio Build output the Message in the Target element having a custom name?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, msbuild, projects-and-solutions

My project has a different behaviour locally and on production.
I have concluded that some Tasks in my .vbproj don't get executed locally neither in DEBUG or RELEASE mode. For example, I have a Message in a  element, and it doesn't appear in the OUTPUT window after build.

Is my conclusion wrong? Am I missing something here?

**doesn't display message in console:**

```
<Target Name="test12345">
 <Message Text="This is a test message" Importance="high" />
</Target>
```

**displays message in console:**

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
 <Message Text="This is a test message" Importance="high" />
</Target>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `AfterBuild` name makes it automatically run after a project is built (to be specific, `AfterBuild` is already defined but meant to be overwritten in custom projects).

When you define a target with a custom name, you need to hook it into the build as well, e.g. by using `AfterTargets`:

```
<Target Name="test12345" AfterTargets="Build">
 <Message Text="This is a test message" Importance="high" />
</Target>
```